# How to have turtle write one line at a time if they click on the screen

Tags: python, csv, python-turtle

So example: *click*
first line is written
*click*
second line
so on
this is what I have so far
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySvLB.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)